# Advanced file descriptor redirecting, how to handle multiple file descriptors at once

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I know basic redirection, but I'm confused how should I handle situations with multiple file descriptors at once.

For example, I have script that writes to FDs `1`, `2` and `3`. I want to output `script::1` and `script::2` to stderr and `script::3` to stdout.

Something like this, which doesn't work:

```
./script.sh \
    1>&2 \
    2>&2 \
    3>&1
```

How does redirection how I would like to do work? I have no idea what to search for.

I know I can work around this, and I actually already have to workaround ready, but I'd like to know how to do advanced magic like this. Maybe something with redirecting to `/proc/self/fd/{1,2}`?

```
 +-----------+            +-----------------+
 |           >1 ---+---- 2>                 |
 | script.sh >2 ---^      |       TTY       |
 |           >3 -------- 1>                 |
 +-----------+            +-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have `script` that writes to FDs `1`, `2` and `3`. I want to output `script::1` and `script::2` to stderr and `script::3` to stdout.

Just change the order:

```
./script.sh 3>&1 1>&2
```

[ you can omit the `2>&2`, you only have to that [in ksh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517541/308316) for fds greater than 2 ;-) ]

Most confusion with fd redirecting operators comes from the fact that people seem to attach magical properties to the `>` or `<` characters -- in fact, **`>&` and `<&` are 100% identical**.

Every time you see `p>&q` or `p<&q` where `p` and `q` are numbers, parse it as a `fd_p = fd_q` assignment.

Then it's easy to see that if you start with `fd1: out` and `fd2: err`, `fd3=fd1 fd1=fd2` evaluated from left to right will  result in `fd1: err`, `fd2: err` and `fd3: out`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, so in my example, I pointed `fd1` to whatever `fd2` pointed to (stderr) and the last redirection pointed `fd3` to whatever `fd1` pointed to, which was set to stderr by that time. But in your example, you first pointed `fd3` to whatever `fd1` pointed to (stdout) and then pointed `fd1` to whatever `fd2` pointed to (stderr), correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Huh. I mean you gotta admit that having two different syntaxes which are suggestive of meaning opposite things, but which actually mean the same thing, is kind of confusing! Thank you for pointing that out.